# Help in proof of trignometry

Tags: trigonometry

I know that

[image]

But I don't know how to prove

[image]

Can anybody provide me a hint

Comment: Allen student , right? (This question is from today's Score test series)

Comment: What did you mean by this comment? Is it worthy?

Comment: @JaideepKhare  Are you saying that this is a question on a live exam or something like that?  If so, we should move to close it.

Comment: @lulu It's an exact question from mock test series for an engineering entrance exam.(This is question from today's test)

Comment: @JeanMarie No I'm not a teacher, I am a student of a coaching institute named 'Allen Career Insitute' . I also gave mock test today, therefore I recognize this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just $$\frac{1}{8}\left(9\tan27^{\circ}-3\tan9^{\circ}+27\tan81^{\circ}-9\tan27^{\circ}+81\tan243^{\circ}-27\tan81^{\circ}+243\tan729^{\circ}-81\tan243^{\circ}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}(243\tan729^{\circ}-3\tan9^{\circ})=30\tan9^{\circ}$$